# Android calculating value for letters

Tags: java, android

i am developing an Android app... which is an app based on numerology where ... A-I have a value from 1-9 and then J-R and S-Z so each letter have values and calculate it... I need to display a resultt where users firstname is calculated for example my name is ROSHAN PETER ... my first name is ROSHAN and last name PETER so value is 9 + 6 + 1 + 8 + 1 + 5 ie, total value is 30 ... next my age is taken my age is 27 so I need to take upto ROSHA because its total value is 25 and when I calculate the value of N it will become 30. So I need to display like my current value is N till 30 year. suppose my name is RAM my total value is 9 + 1 + 4 so value is 14 and my age is 27 so I need to calculate the total of RAM once agin so it will get 28 so my current letter is M..
I did code like this but my problem is... my value of first name is calculating one time .. but I need to calculate it till my age comes ... take example for name RAM ...

I am updating my code here..

MainActivity

```
public void gReport(View V)
{

    long sum17 = 0;

    EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
    EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText2);
    EditText et3 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText3);
    EditText et7 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText7);        
    EditText et8 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText8);
    EditText et9 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText9);

    sum17 = getSum17(et1.getText().toString());

    Intent i = new Intent(this, FullExplanation.class);

    int day = Integer.parseInt(et7.getText().toString());
    int month = Integer.parseInt(et8.getText().toString());
    int year = Integer.parseInt(et9.getText().toString());

    String s = String.valueOf(FullExplanationEntry.this.getAge(year, month, day));

    i.putExtra("name17", sum17 + "");
    i.putExtra("a", s + "");
    startActivity(i);
}

private long getSum17(String text) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    long sum17 = 0;
    EditText et7 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText7);        
    EditText et8 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText8);
    EditText et9 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText9);
    int day = Integer.parseInt(et7.getText().toString());
    int month = Integer.parseInt(et8.getText().toString());
    int year = Integer.parseInt(et9.getText().toString());

    String s = String.valueOf(FullExplanationEntry.this.getAge(year, month, day));

    long t = Integer.parseInt(s);
    char[] name17 = new char[text.length()];

    name17 = text.toCharArray();

    for(int i=0; i<text.length(); i++)
    {
        if(sum17 < t) {
            sum17 += value17( name17[i] );
        } else if (sum17 == t) {
            return sum17;
        } else {
            return sum17;
        }
    }
    return sum17;
}

private long value17(char a) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(a)
    {
       case 'A': 
       return 1;    
       case 'B':
       return 2;
       case 'C':
       return 3;
       case 'D':
       return 4;
       case 'E':
       return 5;
       case 'F':
       return 6;
       case 'G':
       return 7;
       case 'H':
       return 8;
       case 'I':
       return 9;
       case 'J':
       return 1;
       case 'K':
       return 2;
       case 'L':
       return 3;
       case 'M':
       return 4;
       case 'N':
       return 5;
       case 'O':
       return 6;
       case 'P':
       return 7;
       case 'Q':
       return 8;
       case 'R':
       return 9;
       case 'S':
       return 1;          
       case 'T':
       return 2;
       case 'U':
       return 3;
       case 'V':
       return 4;
       case 'W':
       return 5;
       case 'X':
       return 6;
       case 'Y':
       return 7;
       case 'Z':
       return 8;
       default:         
       return 0;

    }

}

public int getAge (int _year, int _month, int _day) {

        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        int y, m, d, a;         

        y = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        m = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        d = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        cal.set(_year, _month, _day);
        a = y - cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        if ((m < cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)
                        || ((m == cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) && (d < cal
                                        .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)))) {
                --a;
        }
        if(a < 0)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Age < 0");
        return a;
}
```

Comment: Don't use non-nonsense names for your variables, especially when someone else is trying to read your code.. Save us time and write legible code. ALSO COMMENTS ARE USEFUL, don't follow bad programming practice.

Comment: Sorry Jox .... I will surely do this from my next coding... Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, my friend, your code is nigh incomprehensible. However, I had a lot of time on my hands tonight, so I waded through it. In order to understand what you were trying to accomplish, I've renamed some of your variables, but this code should work without having to alter anything other than your MainActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    EditText edtFirst, edtMiddle, edtLast, edtDay, edtMonth, edtYear;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        edtFirst = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        edtMiddle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        edtLast = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        edtDay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);        
        edtMonth = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8);
        edtYear = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText9);
    }

    public void gReport(View v)
    {
        String first = edtFirst.getText().toString();

        if (first.length() == 0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a First Name.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            int day = Integer.parseInt(edtDay.getText().toString());
            int month = Integer.parseInt(edtMonth.getText().toString());
            int year = Integer.parseInt(edtYear.getText().toString());

            int age = getAge(year, month, day);
            int sum17 = getSum17(first, age);

            Intent i = new Intent(this, FullExplanation.class);
            i.putExtra("name17", sum17);
            i.putExtra("age", age);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter Day, Month, and Year", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
        {           
            Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid Birthdate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private int getSum17(String name, int age)
    {
        int sum17 = 0;
        int ct = 0;
        boolean done = false;

        char[] name17 = name.toUpperCase().toCharArray();

        if (name17.length == 0 || value17(name17[0]) > age)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        do
        {
            sum17 += value17(name17[ct]);
            ct++;

            if (ct > name.length() - 1)
            {
                ct = 0;
            }

            if (sum17 + value17(name17[ct]) > age)
            {
                done = true;
            }
        }
        while (!done);

        return sum17;       
    }

    private int value17(char c)
    {
        if (c < 65 || c > 90)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        int v = (c - 64) % 9;
        return v == 0 ? 9 : v;      
    }

    public int getAge(int _year, int _month, int _day)
    {
        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        int y, m, d, a;         

        y = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        m = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        d = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        cal.set(_year, _month, _day);
        a = y - cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        if ((m < cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)
            || ((m == cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) && (d < cal
            .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))))
        {
            --a;
        }
        if (a < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Age < 0");
        return a;
    }
}
```

Now, updating just your MainActivity should get you running. However, if you would like, you can also make the following changes to help prevent the user from causing a runtime error.

In your layout xml, in each of the EditTexts for the name, add the following line, keeping the space between the alphabets:

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

And in each of the EditTexts  for the birthdate, add:

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Let me know if you've any questions.